# What does the php insert code look like when dealing with ajax and serialized data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

**UPDATE II**

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var $form = $( this ),
url = $form.attr( 'action' );
var posting = $.post( url, {
id: $('#id').val(),
name: $('#name').val(),
wname: $('#wname').val(),
xcor: $('#xcor').val(),
ycor: $('#ycor').val(),
xwid: $('#xwid').val(),
yhei: $('#yhei').val(),
photo: $('#photo').val(),
targeturl: $('#targeturl').val()
});

posting.done(function( data ){
alert('success');
});
});
```

**UPDATE**

This does not work... the `alert('nice');` is not triggered

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
var postData = $(this).seralizeArray();
var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
$.ajax({
url : formURL,
type : "POST",
data : postData
});
e.preventDefault();
e.unbind();
});
$("#form").submit();
alert('nice');
```

My goal is to send data with a form through ajax and the page does not refresh.

I am not using a button, the submit is triggered by a javascript function which triggers the ajax

The serialized data I had follows the format of

`name=name$email=email` etc...

I don't know what to do with this string

This is what I have on the sending page

```
var frm = $('#form');
var formData = $('#form').serialize();
frm.submit(function (ev) {
$.ajax({
type: frm.attr('method'),
data: formData,
url: frm.attr('action'),
success: function (data) {
alert('successful update');
}
});
ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Does the serialized data get appended to a URL? I mean I realize upon submission the current page does not go anywhere so how would that work as far as the action page "seeing the url and pulling it" so to speak...

My action page is the cliche design of a form being submitted by a button on the same page mostly it is a declaration of the variables and then an insert line

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email= $_POST['email'];

 $link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$name,$email);

        $stmt->execute();
```

I apologize if this is clearly wrong, I haven't used serialized form data submission before

Comment: Your serialized data should become POST data (if your form method property is POST). In your PHP, the variables will be in $_POST. "Does the serialized data get appended to a URL?". No, not the URL. The body of the HTTP request which PHP will parse and covert into a $_POST array.

Comment: HTTP request? Did I miss that? I haven't wrote any code regarding HTTP request or the word GET which I'm not saying you mentioned but it comes to mind. How are the two pages bridged? The first page being the form and the second page being the php insert to database.

Comment: $.ajax will create an HTTP request. The HTTP verb will be whatever is in the "method" property of your form, because this line: `type: frm.attr('method'),` will take whatever's in there (e.g. <form method="POST"> and use it as the HTTP verb. POST parameters are sent in the body of the HTTP request in the format you describe above (name={var}&email={var}). These parameters will end up in your $_POST array in PHP.

Comment: I've tried so many methods to send the data, I don't know why it isn't going through. I'm wondering how I can tell if the script is even seeing the request... I will try the insert manually to be sure that it actually works. I added another update above of my current attempt

Comment: Here's a dumb question: is there supposed to be an if(){ POST } argument on the receiving PHP? The insert works stand alone without the if post, but I tried both methods of with and without the if post and sending the data, hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form method `frm.attr('method')` is POST, the serialized data does not get put in the URL but instead in the HTTP request body.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body

If the form method is GET then the data would be appended to the end of the URL like so:
`http://yoursite.com/yourrequestpage?name=yourname&email=youremail`

If you are using the GET method then on the PHP side, you would have to use `$_GET['email']` instead of `$_POST['email']`.

I also see that `var formData = $('#form').serialize();` is out of the form submission function body. This should be put in the body so that it is initialized when the form is submitted (when you have filled out the form), not when the page is loaded (when you haven't yet interacted with the form).

Comment: The formData is serializing properly, as I am seeing a complete output. I am trying to use POST, I mean really I want it to work is the bottom line. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It looks to me like you're on the right track. My last paragraph might be helpful if you find that your PHP script is not receiving anything from the request.

Comment: If the form is not triggered by a click, what should go in the place of (el) which I read briefly it is el for element and ev for click event anyway I tried to leave it blank, did not work.  If I try to alert something within the frm.submit(function (){ }, no alerts show up, is that expected or does that indicate that it is not working properly?

Comment: 'el' is just the event object passed when the submission is triggered. You could inspect in the console or by setting a breakpoint to see what is inside. There probably isn't anything useful for your purposes in there.

Comment: I wrote an update above, if you wouldn't mind looking